# How do I create a new notebook in ipython notebook?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm trying to create a new notebook in ipython but the notebook option is greyed out.  I first of all open a console and go to the ipython folder and launch using ipyhon notebook.  I get the following messages which don't look like errors:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\aurquhart>cd ipython
>
> C:\Users\ipython>ipython notebook [I 09:20:46.487 NotebookApp] Using
>   existing profile dir: 'C:\Users\ ipython\profile_default' [I
>   09:20:46.501 NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN:
>   https://cdn.mathjax.org/mat hjax/latest/MathJax.js [I 09:20:46.563
>   NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users \ipython
>   [I 09:20:46.564 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels [I 09:20:46.564
>   NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhos
>   t:8888/ [I 09:20:46.564 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server
>   and shut down all  kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

It does then open a browser window pointing to http://localhost:8888/tree but the option to add a new notebook is blank.  I can see various python scripts I have in the folder though, although I cannot run them.

Any ideas on how to be able to open a new notebook?

Comment: There is also an option New -> Python 2, which creates new notebook. Is it also blank in your case?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks AniaG - There is an option to add a new Python 3 which does actually create a new notebook.  I tried this before and it didn't work but once I'd navigated to the ipython folder and run ipython from here this option now works.